# I am reading text from file in unix and inserting into table

Tags: sql

I am reading some table names from a Unix file and inserting into  table x (some table names based on some condition )then I am executing this query
The Query is

```
Select table_name from user_tab_columns where table_name =:'P_table_name'
and table_name not in (select table_name from x);
```

Table x contains one column i .e `table_name varchar2 (128)`
Here `P_table_name` is passed one by one from the names read from the unix  file

Result for above query  is no rows selected 
But when I tried the same using minus operator it worked and returned result

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: Judging by varchar2 - Oracle.

Comment: Your table x probably contains NULL rows. For details see - http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17407/10382

Comment: I am using oracle dB here  .  My table x does not contain any  null rows